# should I launch multiple threads if my CPU load suggests otherwise?

Tags: c++, multithreading, binary-search-tree, std

I'm making a program in C++ which counts NGS read alignments against a reference annotation. Basically the program reads both the annotation and alignment file into memory, iterates through the annotation, binary searches the alignment file for a probable location, upon finding this location linear searches a frame that is around that probable location.

Typically I want to keep this frame somewhat large (10000 alignments), so I had the idea to split the frame up and throw parts of it into separate threads.

Everything compiles and runs, but it doesn't look like my multithreading is working as intended because my comp is using one core for the job. Would anyone be kind enough to help me figure this out where I implemented the threading wrong.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/fast-count/?source=directory

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math.h> 
#include "api/BamReader.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace BamTools;

int hit_count = 0;

struct bam_headers{

    string chr;
    int start;

};

struct thread_data{

   int thread_id;
   int total_thread;
   int start_gtf;
   int stop_gtf;

};

struct gtf_headers{

    string chr;
    string source;
    string feature;
    string score;
    string strand;
    string frame;
    string annotation;
    int start;
    int end;

};

void process(int* start_holder, int size, int gtf_start, int gtf_stop){

    //threaded counter process

    for (int t = 0; t < size; t++){
        if((start_holder[t] >= gtf_start) && (start_holder[t] <= gtf_stop)){
            hit_count++;
        }
    }

}

vector <string> find_index(vector <vector <bam_headers> > bams){

    //define vector for bam_index to chromosome

    vector <string> compute_holder;
    for (int bam_idx = 0; bam_idx < bams.size();bam_idx++){
        compute_holder.push_back(bams[bam_idx][0].chr);
    }
    return compute_holder;

}

vector <gtf_headers> load_gtf(char* filename){

    //define matrix to memory holding gtf annotations by assoc. header

    vector<gtf_headers> push_matrix;
    gtf_headers holder;
    ifstream gtf_file(filename);
    string line;

    cout << "Loading GTF to memory" << "\n";
    if (gtf_file.is_open()){
        int sub_count = 0;
        string transfer_hold[8];
        while(getline(gtf_file,line)){
            //iterate through file
            istringstream iss(line);
            string token;
            //iterate through line, and tokenize by tab delimitor
            while(getline(iss,token,'\t')){
                if (sub_count == 8){
                    //assign to hold struct, and push to vector
                    holder.chr = transfer_hold[0];
                    holder.source = transfer_hold[1];
                    holder.feature = transfer_hold[2];
                    holder.start = atoi(transfer_hold[3].c_str());
                    holder.end = atoi(transfer_hold[4].c_str());
                    holder.score = transfer_hold[5];
                    holder.strand = transfer_hold[6];
                    holder.frame = transfer_hold[7];
                    holder.annotation = token;
                    push_matrix.push_back(holder);
                    sub_count = 0;
                } else {
                    //temporarily hold tokens
                    transfer_hold[sub_count] = token;
                    ++sub_count;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "GTF successfully loaded to memory" << "\n";
        gtf_file.close();
        return(push_matrix);
    }else{
        cout << "GTF unsuccessfully loaded to memory. Check path to file, and annotation format. Exiting" << "\n";
        exit(-1);
    }
}

vector <vector <bam_headers>> load_bam(char* filename){

    //parse individual bam file to chromosome bins

    vector <vector <bam_headers> > push_matrix;
    vector <bam_headers> iter_chr;
    int iter_refid = -1;
    bam_headers bam_holder;
    BamReader reader;
    BamAlignment al;
    const vector<RefData>& references = reader.GetReferenceData();

    cout << "Loading " << filename << " to memory" << "\n";
    if (reader.Open(filename)) {    
        while (reader.GetNextAlignmentCore(al)) {
            if (al.IsMapped()){
                //bam file must be sorted by chr. otherwise the lookup will segfault
                if(al.RefID != iter_refid){
                    //check if chr. position has advanced in the bam file, if true, push empty vector
                    iter_refid++;
                    push_matrix.push_back(iter_chr);
                }else{
                    //if chr. position hasn't advanced push to current index in 2d vector
                    bam_holder.chr = references[al.RefID].RefName;
                    bam_holder.start = al.Position;
                    push_matrix.at(iter_refid).push_back(bam_holder);
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
        cout << "Successfully loaded " << filename << " to memory" << "\n";
        return(push_matrix);
    }else{
        cout << "Could not open input BAM file. Exiting." << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }

}

short int find_bin(const string & gtf_chr, const vector <string> mapping){

    //determines which chr. bin the gtf line is associated with 

    int bin_compare = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mapping.size(); i++){
        if(gtf_chr == mapping[i]){ 
            bin_compare = i;
        }
    }
    return(bin_compare);

}

int find_frame(gtf_headers gtf_matrix, vector <bam_headers> bam_file_bin){

    //binary search to find alignment index with greater and less than gtf position

    int bin_size = bam_file_bin.size();
    int high_end = bin_size;
    int low_end = 0;
    int binary_i = bin_size / 2;
    int repeat = 0;
    int frame_start;
    bool found = false;

    while (found != true){
        if ((bam_file_bin[binary_i].start >= gtf_matrix.start) && (bam_file_bin[binary_i].start <= gtf_matrix.end)){
            frame_start = binary_i;
            found = true;
        }else{
            if(repeat != binary_i){
                if(bam_file_bin[binary_i].start > gtf_matrix.end){
                    if(repeat != binary_i){
                        repeat = binary_i;
                        high_end = binary_i;
                        binary_i = ((high_end - low_end) / 2) + low_end;
                    }
                }else{
                    if(repeat != binary_i){
                        repeat = binary_i;
                        low_end = binary_i;
                        binary_i = ((high_end - low_end) / 2) + low_end;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                frame_start = low_end; 
                found = true;
            }
        }   
    }
    return(frame_start);
}

vector <int > define_frame(int frame_size, int frame_start, int bam_matrix){

    //define the frame for the search
    vector <int> push_ints;
    push_ints.push_back(frame_start - (frame_size / 2)); 
    push_ints.push_back(frame_start + (frame_size / 2)); 
    if(push_ints[0] < 0){
        push_ints[0] = 0;
        push_ints[1] = frame_size;
        if(push_ints[1] > bam_matrix){
            push_ints[1] = frame_size;
        }
    } 
    if(push_ints[1] > bam_matrix){
        push_ints[1] = bam_matrix;
        push_ints[0] = bam_matrix - (frame_size / 2);
        if(push_ints[0] < 0){
            push_ints[0] = 0;
        }
    }
    return(push_ints);

}

void thread_handler(int nthread, vector <int> frame, vector <bam_headers> bam_matrix, gtf_headers gtf_record){

    int thread_divide = frame[1]-frame[0];//frame_size / nthread;
    int thread_remain = (frame[1]-frame[0]) % nthread;
    int* start_holder = new int[thread_divide];

    for(int i = 0; i < nthread; i++){
        if (i < nthread - 1){
            for (int frame_index = 0; frame_index < thread_divide; frame_index++){
                 start_holder[frame_index] = bam_matrix[frame[0]+frame_index].start;         
            } 
            frame[0] = frame[0] + thread_divide;
            thread first(process, start_holder,thread_divide,gtf_record.start,gtf_record.end);
            first.join();
        }else{
            for (int frame_index = 0; frame_index < thread_divide + thread_remain; frame_index++){
                 start_holder[frame_index] = bam_matrix[frame[0]+frame_index].start;    
            } 
            thread last(process, start_holder,thread_divide + thread_remain,gtf_record.start,gtf_record.end);
            last.join();
        }
    }

}



int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    // usage
    // ./count threads frame_size gtf_file files

    //define matrix to memory holding gtf annotations by assoc. header
    vector <gtf_headers> gtf_matrix = load_gtf(argv[3]);

    //load bam, perform counts
    for(int i = 4;i < argc;i++){

        //iterate through filenames in argv, define matrix to memory holding bam alignments chr and bp position
        vector <vector <bam_headers> > bam_matrix = load_bam(argv[i]);

        //map chromosome to bam matrix index
        vector <string> index_mapping = find_index(bam_matrix);

        //iterate through gtf matrix, find corresponding bins for chr, set search frames, and count
        for(int gtf_i = 0; gtf_i < gtf_i < gtf_matrix.size();gtf_i++){ //gtf_i < gtf_matrix.size()

            hit_count = 0;
            //find corresponding bins for gtf chr
            short int bin_compare = find_bin(gtf_matrix[gtf_i].chr,index_mapping);

            if(bin_compare != -1){

                //find start of search frame
                int frame_start = find_frame(gtf_matrix[gtf_i], bam_matrix[bin_compare]);

                //get up lower bounds of search frame;
                vector <int> full_frame = define_frame(atoi(argv[2]),frame_start,bam_matrix[bin_compare].size());

                //create c array of bam positional data for the frame, and post to thread process
                thread_handler(atoi(argv[1]),full_frame,bam_matrix[bin_compare],gtf_matrix[gtf_i]);

            }

            //counts displayed in STOUT
            cout << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].chr << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].source << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].feature << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].start << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].end << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].score << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].strand << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].frame << "\t" << gtf_matrix[gtf_i].annotation << "\t" << hit_count << "\n";

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating multiple threads does not guarantee that multiple cores will be used.  The OS could schedule multiple threads on the same core, if it considers it necessary/worthwhile to do so.  The STL's `std::thread` class does not let you control which core runs which thread, but there may be platform specific APIs that can (like `SetThreadAffinityMask()` and `SetThreadIdealProcessor/Ex()` on Windows).

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestion, Remy.

Comment: Unfortunately, that suggestion is irrelevant, since your code, by design, will never start more than one thread at a time.

Comment: Assigning threads to a specific core is bad design usually. Some cores could be more loaded... If you have more cores and more threads that have some work to do in same time, then the threads usually will be assigned to cores separate cores as the system seems fit. Controlling assignment is a bad idea. In this case, something like MS PPL or Intel TBB would be way better approach as it handles load balancing dynamically...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is very simple:

```
thread last(process, start_holder,thread_divide + thread_remain,gtf_record.start,gtf_record.end);
last.join();
```

Here, the parent task creates a new thread, and ... immediately waits for the thread to finish. That's what join() does, it waits for the thread to terminate.

So, your code starts a new thread, and immediately waits for it to finish, before doing anything else, like starting the next thread.

You need to rewrite thread_handler() to instantiate all `std::thread` instances, and then after instantiating all of them, call `join()` on each one, to wait for all of them to finish.

The typical approach is to precreate a `std::vector` of all thread instances, using `std::thread`'s default constructor, then loop over them to initialize each one, then loop over them again, calling `join`() on each one.

Comment: Say the number of threads is determined at run time by the user. If I instantiate them all, then loop through a vector of threads and join on each iteration would that achieve the desired result? Or would the thread wait till the thread had finished prior to iterating to the next join call?

Comment: `vector <thread> thread_holder;
//instantiate threads
for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
   thread_holder.push_back(thread(command));
}
//join threads
for (int x = 0; x < thread_holder.size(); x++){
   thread_holder[x].join();
}`

Comment: So it looks like this doesn't solve the issue. It's still only using one core. I was thinking that the compute isn't large enough, however when I reduce the number of cores and increase the frame I still see no change in core use. For example, if I change the thread number from 16 to 2, and increase the frame from 10,000 to 300,000,000, I see no change in CPU usage. Not only that, but it doesn't look like there is a noticeable difference in how fast it takes to compute. You'd think that increasing the workload per core by 240,000x would do something rather than nothing.